# Fixing a choppy-looking countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my countdown timer to look right. As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c5m0h1w/), the numbers are moving around a bit as the countdown timer goes down. Is there a way to fix this so that the timer stays in position while the numbers decrease? Thanks in advance.

Also, this is the specific code used to display the timer:

```
view.displayTimer = function() {
  var count = 500;
  var counter = setInterval(timer, 10);

  function timer() {
    if(count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }
    count--;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count / 100;
  }
};
```

Comment: FYI, this is not a very accurate way to do a timer because `setInterval()` is only an approximation.  You should record the startTime and then on each interval tick, calculate the elapsed time since the start time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use javascript [`toFixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) function to pad with trailing zeros.

Replace

```
count / 100;
```

With

```
(count / 100).toFixed(2);
```

[Jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8c5m0h1w/1/)

Comment: Thank you! So I'm assuming that it was being choppy because the amount of decimal places were changing as the timer went down?

Comment: Yep that's right - by default javascript will give you the shortest float representation of your number. `toFixed` ensures you'll always have a minimum number of numbers shown after the decimal point.

Comment: Yup, just waiting 1 more min til it lets me accept an answer.

Comment: Ahhhh cool that makes sense. Sorry and thanks :) (I forgot there's a limit to how soon you can accept an answer)